# Rails: undefined method error for form label and text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My `show.html.erb` is literally just a page that has User information and has a text field + button that one can type in.

For some reason, Heroku crashes when I try to go to `show.html.erb`, the logs which can be seen in this [public gist.](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/wangjess/121e58b733c70a6ec44a21ca25687c95.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

On line 26, it's clear that it doesn't like my naming `wistia_project_id`. However, this is just the name of the column that I created for my Users table, and it's also what I want to call the text field.

It is not a method. It's literally just my `wistia_project_id` name.

For those curious why I want to do this, I want to `put` this to my database, updating the `wistia_project_id` column in the database.

I am new to Rails and I don't understand this error.

Comment: Please paste your schema for the users table.

Comment: And did you add `wistia_project_id` column? Was it via migration? Did it run on your remote db?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky It was via migration. I didn't run it on my remote DB, but I just did and it WORKED!!! :D I will give you the points for this.